# Firefox autofill puts input on top of loading div

Tags: reactjs, firefox, autofill

I am attempting to make a pretty basic form with React that has some inputs and a submit button. When the submit button is pressed, a loading screen that is basically just a div with opacity 0.9 is supposed to cover the screen. If the form is filled using autofill (or autcomplete, whichever is the one where the browser fills in the whole form for you), the inputs on the form are not covered by the loading screen, and I can edit them as if they are on top of the div. 
Here is an example of the problem [image]

If I autofill the form and then edit one of the inputs manually, that input will be covered by the div while the rest are still on top of it. I'm not sure what the issue is or if it can even be fixed, but any help is appreciated. [Here is the codepen](https://codepen.io/wbh24/pen/oNgWaab) if you want to try it out.

```
const App = ()=>{
  const [loading, changeLoading] = React.useState(false)
  const submit = (e) =>{
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation;
    changeLoading(true);
  }
  return(
    <div>
      {loading &&
      <div className = 'loading'>
        <h1>Loading...</h1>
      </div>}

      <form autocomplete = 'on' onSubmit = {submit}>
        <label forHtml = 'name'>Name</label>
        <input 
          name = 'name'
          id = 'name'
          autocomplete = 'name'
         />

        <label forHtml = 'email'>Email</label>
        <input 
          name = 'email'
          id = 'email'
          autocomplete = 'email'
         />

        <label forHtml = 'tel'>Phone</label>
        <input 
          name = 'tel'
          id = 'tel'
          autocomplete = 'tel'
         />
        <input 
          type = 'submit'
          onClick = {submit}></input>
      </form>
     </div>
   )
 }
```

This problem does not appear to occur when I use Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved really easily by just adding

```
z-index:1
```

to the loading div.